# JFrame instance doesn't visualise added component

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jcomponent

I created SelectMethodFrame that extends JFrame that can have only one instance:

```
public class SelectMethodFrame extends JFrame {

  private JSplitPane mainWindow = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);

  public JSplitPane getMainWindow() {
    return mainWindow;
  }

  public void setMainWindow(JSplitPane mainWindow) {
    this.mainWindow = mainWindow;
  }

  private static SelectMethodFrame instance = null;



  public static SelectMethodFrame getInstance() {
    if (instance == null)
        instance = new SelectMethodFrame();
    return instance;
 }


  public void setTab(JComponent panelConsumption, JComponent panelCpu,
        JComponent panelMemo, JComponent panelScreen,
        JComponent panelMobile, JComponent panelWifi) {

    TabbedView tab = new TabbedView(panelConsumption, panelCpu, panelMemo,
            panelScreen, panelMobile, panelWifi);


    mainWindow.setRightComponent(tab);


}

  public void setTree(JTree tree) {

    mainWindow.setLeftComponent(new JScrollPane(tree));

    this.pack();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setVisible(true);

    getContentPane().add(mainWindow, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 500));
    this.setTitle(Constants.APP_CHECKBOXTREE);
  }

}
```

I create frame in one class in this way:

```
SelectMethodFrame frame = new SelectMethodFrame();

frame.setTree(treeSelection);
```

And everything works fine but when I want to add another component to my frame in another class:

```
SelectMethodFrame.getInstance().setTab(panelConsumption, panelCpu,
    panelMemo, panelScreen, panelMobile, panelWifi);
```

it doesn't show it. I tried with

```
SelectMethodFrame.getInstance().repaint();
SelectMethodFrame.getInstance().revalidate();
```

but it doesn't work. It shows component only if created in the constructor. Where is the problem?

I changed the code and put:

public SelectMethodFrame() {

```
    this.pack();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setVisible(true);

    getContentPane().add(mainWindow, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 500));
    this.setTitle(Constants.APP_CHECKBOXTREE);

}
```

instead in

```
public void setTree(JTree tree) {

    mainWindow.setLeftComponent(new JScrollPane(tree));

    this.pack();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setVisible(true);

    getContentPane().add(mainWindow, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 500));
    this.setTitle(Constants.APP_CHECKBOXTREE);
  }
```

now it opens it in another frame but shows only the last component added. It so strange..

Comment: might be related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577924/jframe-with-tabs-is-not-being-displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not implementing the [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern correctly.

In the `SelectMethodFrame` class, set the constructor as private:

```
public class SelectMethodFrame extends JFrame {
    private SelectMethodFrame (){}
    ...
}
```

And in all references to the singleton inside the class, instead `this`, use the `instance` variable, like:

```
instance.pack();
instance.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
instance.setVisible(true);
//etc...
```

This way you can't call `new SelectMethodFrame()` externally. So, instead:

```
SelectMethodFrame frame = new SelectMethodFrame();
```

You should use:

```
SelectMethodFrame frame = SelectMethodFrame.getInstance();
```

It avoids the creation of more than one instance of the class.